# How to connect two react apps in a performant way

Tags: reactjs, authentication, routes, dashboard

I'm trying to implement a system, where the users can access the dashboard only if they are signed in. New users will be directed to the home page. If the user is logged in, they should be directly routed to the dashboard instead of the home page.

The dashboard is a completely different entity and doesn't contain any home page components.
The home page only has sign-in and signup buttons through which the users can login or create an account.

I'm using React for both the homepage and dashboard. Should I implement both of them in a single react app or as two different apps.

What are some of the best practices and authentication methods to implement this?

[image]

Comment: You may use either. Depending on the size of the project but as long as you handle authentication you will be fine. I would probably prefer to have two different apps if it is a bigger production website for a clear separation of applications. At my company, we have an eCommerce frontend with an entirely separate admin app. If the apps share backend logic it doesn't seem as important.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if the app is going to scale in the future depending on the plans. But as far now the application is relatively small. My only concern is I shouldn't rewrite the app in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You should use one react app for both components. You can write a protected route to check if a user is logged in or not. You can also write a redirection login inside the ProtectedRoute component.
for details refer this article:
https://dev.to/mychal/protected-routes-with-react-function-components-dh

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yeah, I came across that, but what about the loading time of the page if a new user only wants to view the website. In that case, the dashboard is also fetched along with the homepage which adds some overhead in page loading time.

Comment: If you make the dashboard's route a protected route then it won't be overhead. it would only display one of a component so I don't think it will be overhead in your case.

Comment: any frontend logic could be disclosed by an experienced user